# Unable to parse valid json file in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a json file using Python3.6 and json module. Unfortunately, I get this error:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

I tried with both `json.load()` and `json.loads()` methods, but I still have this error. I do not understand from where this error comes from, due to the fact that my JSON does not have single quotes.

The JSON is the next one:

```
{
    "stats": {
        "host1": {
            "changed": 0,
            "failures": 0,
            "ok": 1,
            "skipped": 0,
            "unreachable": 0
        },
        "host2": {
            "changed": 0,
            "failures": 0,
            "ok": 1,
            "skipped": 0,
            "unreachable": 0
        },
        "host3": {
            "changed": 0,
            "failures": 0,
            "ok": 1,
            "skipped": 0,
            "unreachable": 0
        },
        "host4": {
            "changed": 0,
            "failures": 0,
            "ok": 0,
            "skipped": 0,
            "unreachable": 1
        }
    }
}
```

And my python code is the next one:

```
import json

json_file = open("example.json", "r")
data = json.load(json_file)
```

I tried other solutions found here, but no one worked for me. Any suggestion/solution is highly apreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error.  It works fine for me, using Python 3.6

Comment: You say your JSON looks "something" like that, can you post the actual thing?

Comment: The error message says the error is in the first line. Can you at least post the actual first line? Additionally, if you are on Linux/UNIX can you post `hd example.json | head -1`

Comment: @chrisz I just updated the post with the original json. I didn`t realized that the initial one was actually working.

Comment: No issues with that the updated one either for me.

Comment: Now, when I copy/pasted  from my stackoverflow post it worked for me as well, I guess it was only an indentation problem or something like that. Anyway, thank you, now everything works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON file is encoded UTF-16-LE, but you are reading it with the default encoding.

Try this:

```
json_file = open("example.json", "r", encoding='utf_16_le')
```

Comment: Great catch! For the curious, I imagine this is how he knew: `column 2 (char 1)`. The only way this would be the case is if it's encoded in UTF-16.